# TYPO3 tx_news, issue with the position of widget.paginate

Tags: pagination, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have a problem with the widget.paginate position in the extension tx_news, i'm working in TYPO3 v. 6.1 FLUID/EXTBASE.

My problem is that it's showing the widget.paginate by default, inside the Templates/News/list.html in my list show UL tag. and i want it to be outside the UL tags, I have tryed to move it around, but then it make some big changes to my layout, or do not work at all.

see bottom of page - [enter link description here](http://codem.dk/blog/)

How can I show the paginate links/widget outside the UL and after it ?

My Templates/News/list.html code

```
{namespace n=Tx_News_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="General" />
<!--
  =====================
    Templates/News/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
  <f:if condition="{news}">
    <f:then>
      <div class="news-list-view">
        <ul class="cbp_tmtimeline {newsItem.type}{f:if(condition: newsItem.istopnews, then: ' topnews')}">
        <f:if condition="{settings.hidePagination}">
          <f:then>
            <f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem">
              <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
            </f:for>
          </f:then>
          <f:else>
            <n:widget.paginate objects="{news}" as="paginatedNews" configuration="{settings.list.paginate}">
              <f:for each="{paginatedNews}" as="newsItem">
                <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
              </f:for>
            </n:widget.paginate>
          </f:else>
        </f:if>
       </ul>
      </div>   
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <div class="no-news-found">
        <f:translate key="list_nonewsfound" />
      </div>
    </f:else>
  </f:if>
</f:section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default Paginate Template and define your own Template

Add this to your TS template:

`plugin.tx_news.settings.list.paginate.templatePath = YourNewTemplatePath.html`

To know how the default template works, check out this [Default Template](https://github.com/typo3-ter/news/blob/master/Resources/Private/Templates/ViewHelpers/Widget/Paginate/Index.html) for reference and modify your view accordingly.

If you trying to edit the default News List, change the default news path and write your FLUID template in that file:

`plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPath = YourNewTemplateNews.html`

Close your tag before the widget. Of course, you'll have to make a few changes in your CSS to get what you want.

```
</ul>
          <f:else>
            <n:widget.paginate>.......
```

Comment: Hi RaD0, the default template for the paginate, is working fine, its just the placing of it, thats the problem. so its the n:widget.paginate thats i want to place/call another place on my page.

Comment: If you don't the default template of News List, then it's a good idea to write your own template than changing what comes with Extension by default. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i fix it in the Templates/News/list.html code

with this code.

```
{namespace n=Tx_News_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="General" />
<!--
  =====================
    Templates/News/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
  <f:if condition="{news}">
    <f:then>
        <f:if condition="{settings.hidePagination}">
          <f:then>
            <f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem">
              <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
            </f:for>
          </f:then>
          <f:else>  
            <n:widget.paginate objects="{news}" as="paginatedNews" configuration="{settings.list.paginate}">       
            <div class="news-list-view">
            <ul class="cbp_tmtimeline {newsItem.type}{f:if(condition: newsItem.istopnews, then: ' topnews')}">            
              <f:for each="{paginatedNews}" as="newsItem">
                <f:render partial="List/Item" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
              </f:for>         
            </ul>
           </div>
           </n:widget.paginate>
          </f:else>
        </f:if>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <div class="no-news-found">
        <f:translate key="list_nonewsfound" />
      </div>
    </f:else>
  </f:if>
</f:section>
```